# Function with toggle options

Tags: java, enums

I've made a basic function to check a password complies with various business rules. Has an upper case character, has a number etc.

I'd like to make this function more flexible and configurable by toggling these options on and off as desired. The only way I can think of to do this is as so:

```
public static boolean isPasswordValid(String pwd, boolean checkUpper, boolean checkLower, boolean checkNum) {
    boolean hasUppercase = !pwd.equals(pwd.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
    boolean hasLowercase = !pwd.equals(pwd.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
    boolean hasNumeric = pwd.matches(".*\\d+.*");

    boolean isValid = false;

    if(checkUpper){
        if(hasUppercase) {
            isValid = true;
        }else{
            return isValid;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

I feel like there is a much better method, using Enums or something. I'd like to be able to pass in the password and just one extra parameter to act as a flag to enable various checks. Inevitably I'll need to add more as time goes on.

If I were to use enums, by my way of thinking, I'd have to define one eNum for every possible case. i.e. upper, upper_and_lower, upper_and_numeric. Which would get very complex if I had to add in more options.

Any ides and suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EnumSet, which is a specialized set for enums.

```
public static enum Validation {
    UPPER, LOWER, DIGIT //etc.
}

public static boolean isPasswordValid(String pwd, EnumSet<Validation> validations) {
//...
}
```

Then, you can use any combination of validations by adding necessary values to the set. Example:

```
EnumSet<Validation> validation = EnumSet.of(Validation.UPPER, Validation.LOWER);
if (isPasswordValid(pass, validation)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was hoping for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Less Simple, but really flexible, using method chaining:

```
public abstract class Clause {
   public abstract boolean match(string value);

}

public final class UpperCaseClause extends Clause {
   @Override
   public boolean match(string value) {
    return !value.equals(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
   }
}

public final class LowerCaseClause extends Clause {
   @Override
   public override boolean match(string value) {
    return !value.equals(value.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
   }
}   

public final class NumericClause extends Clause {
   @Override
   public override boolean match(string value) {
    return value.matches(".*\\d+.*");
   }
}

public final class Validator {
    private List<Clause> clauses;

    public Validator() {
       clauses = new ArrayList<Clause>();
    }

    public Validator addClause(Clause toAdd) {  
       clauses.add(toAdd);
       return this;
    }

    public boolean valid(string value) {         
       boolean isValid = true;
       for(clause in clauses) {
               isValid &= clause.match(value);
           if (!isValid) {
               break;
           }
       }
       return isValid;
    }
}


   [... you could create this anywhere and cache it]
   Validator allValidator = new Validator().addClause(new UpperCaseClause())
                                .addClause(new LowerCaseClause())
                                .addClause(new NumericClause());
   [...]

    public static boolean isPasswordValid(String pwd, Validator validator) {
       validator.valid(pwd);
    }

    [... then pass in the validator you wish to use]
        isPasswordValid(pwd, allValidator);
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but this isn't quite what I'm asking. Whilst your code is cleaner, I'm hoping to avoid passing in a boolean for every check. i.e. I'd like to remove checkUpper, checkLower and checkNum

Comment: There is no "override" keyword in java. You can use the @Override annotation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/20):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

You validate for password with all three combinations (number, upper, lower case alphabets)

```
String pwd = "aaaaaaabbbbCCCC43333333222111";
if (pwd.matches("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$")) {
    System.out.println("It has all three combinations");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid password");
}
Output:
It has all three combinations
```